# Imagens com PHP

Tags: php, imagem

Olá pessoal estou trabalhando com o site de uma banda e preciso fazer com que suas ultimas fotos do instagram apareçam em uma determinada área do site deles, vocês poderiam me dar alguma ideia de como fazer isso?
Não posso incorporá-las, essa sincronização tem que ser feita automaticamente

Comment: Existem várias bibliotecas na internet que fazem isso, tudo fácil e simples

Comment: Poderia me falar mais sobre isso?

Comment: São trechos de código que você usa a api do instagram para capturar as imagens de um perfil especifico.

Comment: Qual é a sua real necessidade? Pois você consegue obter esse resultado facilmente com a documentação do Instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Poderá fazer com json, para que consiga captar as imagens.

Answer (score 2):

### Não-Oficial:

Qualquer website do Facebook possui o parâmetro `?__a=1`, isso é bem curioso e não me pergunte a razão disso existir, mas ele existe. Muitos recursos usando esse parâmetro retorna tudo em JSON, *ou próximo de um JSON*, por exemplo, se utilizar:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4&__a=1
```

Irá retornar o link do perfil.

Se utilizar:

```
https://www.facebook.com/settings/applications/typeahead?__a=1
```

Irá obter a lista de todos os aplicativos que o usuário conectado possui instalado, em JSON.

---

Com o Instagram não é diferente, se você fizer:

```
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
```

Irá obter todos os resultados em JSON, incluindo as últimas publicações, que é o que deseja, assim como o URL, a quantidade de curtidas. *Enfim recomendo que acesse o URL acima, que é o perfil do "Instagram", e veja o que é retornado.*

Usando este URL é possível então utilizar o CURL para obter as informações, por exemplo, para simplificar utilizando a função:

```
function getInstagramContent(string $usuario, bool $isSeguro = true){

    $ch = curl_init('https://www.instagram.com/'.$usuario.'/?__a=1');

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 1500,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => $isSeguro ? 2 : 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $isSeguro ? 1 : 0,
        CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
    ]);

    $conteudo = curl_exec($ch);
    $codigoHTTP = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $codigoHTTP === 200 && $conteudo != '' ? json_decode($conteudo, true) : false;

}
```

---

Dessa forma poderá consumir a função da seguinte maneira:

```
if($conteudoInstagram = getInstagramContent('inkeliz', false)) {

    if($conteudoInstagram['user']['is_private'] === false) {

        foreach ($conteudoInstagram['user']['media']['nodes'] as $indice => $conteudoFoto) {

            $HTML = '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/' . $conteudoFoto['code'] . '">
                    <img src="' . $conteudoFoto['thumbnail_src'] . '">
                </a>';

            echo $HTML;

        }

    }

}
```

---

> **Isso não é oficial e nem sequer está documentado pelo Instagram!**

---

**Explicações:**

```
getInstagramContent(string $usuario, bool $isSeguro = true)
```

O `$usuario` define o nome do Instagram enquanto o segundo argumento (`$isSeguro`) define se deseja verificar ou não o SSL, por padrão irá verificar, *inclusive este é o padrão do PHP 7.1*.

A função retornará um JSON (em formato de array) ou irá retornar `false` se algo der errado.

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
```

Permite o CURL receber os resultados.

```
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => 1500,
```

Faz o CURL ser cancelado se demorar mais de 1500 milissegundos.

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
```

Faz o CURL seguir um possível `Location:`.

```
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2,
```

Define o máximo de redirecionamentos de 2.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => $isSeguro ? 2 : 0,
```

Se `isSeguro` for `true` irá verificar se o SSL presente no `https://www.instagram.com` é realmente do `https://www.instagram.com` e se o  `isSeguro` for `false` nada é verificado.

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => $isSeguro ? 1 : 0,
```

Se `isSeguro` for `true`irá verificar se certificado do `https://www.instagram.com` é válido usando o `CA Bundle`presente no seu dispositivo, assim verifica se o certificado é assinado por um
autoridade que confia. Na condição de `isSeguro` ser `false` nada é verificado.

```
CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
```

Faz o CURL utilizar apenas utilizar o `IPv4`.

---

<sub>Não considero uma boa pergunta, entretanto já possuía a resposta, uma vez que desenvolvi isto para o blog, tempos atrás. A única mudança foi tornar isso em uma função e poucas mudanças foram feitas.</sub>

Você pode fazer um CURL do `$conteudoFoto['thumbnail_src']` afim de baixar a imagem e armazenar em disco local, assim removendo a necessidade de carregar a imagem através do link do Instagram.

---

### Oficial:

Utilize a API do Instagram em https://www.instagram.com/developer/, dessa forma crie um aplicativo e em "Sandbox" adicione a conta que deseja utilizar.

1. Faça o login na conta do Instagram e então acesse:
   `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token`.
2. Obtenha o `access_token`.

Agora basta utilizar o `CURL` para consumir o `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, o `ACCESS-TOKEN` deve ser o `TOKEN` que obteve anteriormente.